# Exception during code generation Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I just tried to load an image from my resources with `val context = ambient(ContextAmbient)` but when I try to run the project I get an error during the generation of the code.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation

```
@Composable
fun MovieImage(image: Int) {
    val context = ambient(ContextAmbient)
    Container(modifier = Modifier.None, width = 24.dp, height = 24.dp) {
        DrawImage(image = imageFromResource( context.resources, image))
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there more to the error message?  It's hard to diagnose without the full stack trace

Comment: yes, It says this too 

Element is unknownThe root cause java.util.NoSuchElementException was thrown at: androidx.compose.plugins.kotlin.compiler.lower.ComposableCallTransformer.irComposableExpr(ComposableCallTransformer.kt:1362)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran in to the same problem when upgrading from `0.1.0-dev03` to `0.1.0-dev05`.
It was solved by adding `composeOptions{ kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "0.1.0-dev05" }` to my `build.gradle` like this:

```
android {
    // ... other gradle properties

    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "0.1.0-dev05"
    }
}
```

Comment: You may find a more recent version over here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose