# IllegalStateException when stringResource() is used while building with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, text-styling

```
            Text(buildAnnotatedString {
                withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color.Red)) {
                    append(stringResource(id = R.string.pre_style))
                }

                append(" ")
                withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, color = Color.Blue)) {
                    //Not able to use string resource here
                     append(stringResource(id = R.string.test_text))
                    //Works 
                     append("Text")
                }
                append("Text")
            },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
```

In the code above, when `stringResource` is used the `IllegalStateException` is thrown. According this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60370133/1169441) `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` is already set. Still the exception is thrown unless hard coded string is used.

Compose beta01 is used to build this.

The exception info is attached below. PS: The complete stack trace is more than 40000 lines which can't be pasted here.

```
Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
w: ATTENTION!
This build uses unsafe internal compiler arguments:

-XXLanguage:+NonParenthesizedAnnotationsOnFunctionalTypes

This mode is not recommended for production use,
as no stability/compatibility guarantees are given on
compiler or generated code. Use it at your own risk!

e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to realize group twice
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer$Scope$BlockScope$markCoalescableGroup$1$1.invoke(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:3574)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer$Scope$BlockScope$markCoalescableGroup$1$1.invoke(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:3526)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer$Scope$BlockScope.realizeCoalescableGroup(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:3620)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer$Scope$BlockScope.realizeGroup(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:3533)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer$Scope$BlockScope$markCoalescableGroup$1.invoke(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:3571)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer$Scope$BlockScope$markCoalescableGroup$1.invoke(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:3526)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer$Scope$BlockScope.realizeCoalescableGroup(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:3620)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.visitComposableLambda(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:950)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.visitFunctionInScope(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:693)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.visitFunction(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:667)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:72)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:73)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrSimpleFunction.accept(IrSimpleFunction.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrFunctionExpressionImpl.transformChildren(IrFunctionExpressionImpl.kt:31)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitExpression(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFunctionExpression(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:233)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFunctionExpression(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:235)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFunctionExpression(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrFunctionExpressionImpl.accept(IrFunctionExpressionImpl.kt:23)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrFunctionAccessExpression.transformChildren(IrFunctionAccessExpression.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoidKt.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:330)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:325)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.visitNormalComposableCall(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:2530)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.visitComposableCall(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:2520)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.visitCall(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:2459)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:199)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrCallImpl.accept(IrCallImpl.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.TransformKt.transformInPlace(transform.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrContainerExpression.transformChildren(IrBlock.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoidKt.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:330)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:325)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.visitRestartableComposableFunction(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:1083)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.visitFunctionInScope(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:698)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.visitFunction(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:667)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:72)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:73)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrSimpleFunction.accept(IrSimpleFunction.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFileImpl.transformChildren(IrFileImpl.kt:71)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitPackageFragment(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFile(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:47)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.visitFile(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:1776)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFile(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFile(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFileImpl.accept(IrFileImpl.kt:63)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrFile.transform(IrFile.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrModuleFragmentImpl.transformChildren(IrModuleFragmentImpl.kt:45)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoidKt.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:330)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.lower(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:453)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeIrGenerationExtension.generate(ComposeIrGenerationExtension.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory$generateModule$1.invoke(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory$generateModule$1.invoke(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:89)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.Psi2IrTranslator.generateModuleFragment(Psi2IrTranslator.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:106)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:595)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:211)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:154)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:169)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:386)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:110)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:286)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:114)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:607)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1659)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to realize group twice
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer$Scope$BlockScope$markCoalescableGroup$1$1.invoke(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:3574)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer$Scope$BlockScope$markCoalescableGroup$1$1.invoke(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:3526)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer$Scope$BlockScope.realizeCoalescableGroup(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:3620)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer$Scope$BlockScope.realizeGroup(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:3533)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer$Scope$BlockScope$markCoalescableGroup$1.invoke(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:3571)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer$Scope$BlockScope$markCoalescableGroup$1.invoke(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:3526)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer$Scope$BlockScope.realizeCoalescableGroup(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:3620)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.visitComposableLambda(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:950)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.visitFunctionInScope(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:693)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.visitFunction(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:667)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:72)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:73)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrSimpleFunction.accept(IrSimpleFunction.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrFunctionExpressionImpl.transformChildren(IrFunctionExpressionImpl.kt:31)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitExpression(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFunctionExpression(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:233)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFunctionExpression(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:235)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFunctionExpression(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrFunctionExpressionImpl.accept(IrFunctionExpressionImpl.kt:23)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrFunctionAccessExpression.transformChildren(IrFunctionAccessExpression.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoidKt.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:330)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:325)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.visitNormalComposableCall(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:2530)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.visitComposableCall(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:2520)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.visitCall(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:2459)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:199)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrCallImpl.accept(IrCallImpl.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.TransformKt.transformInPlace(transform.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrContainerExpression.transformChildren(IrBlock.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoidKt.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:330)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:325)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.visitRestartableComposableFunction(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:1083)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.visitFunctionInScope(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:698)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.visitFunction(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:667)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:72)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:73)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrSimpleFunction.accept(IrSimpleFunction.kt:28)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFileImpl.transformChildren(IrFileImpl.kt:71)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitPackageFragment(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFile(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:47)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.visitFile(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:1776)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFile(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFile(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFileImpl.accept(IrFileImpl.kt:63)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrFile.transform(IrFile.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrModuleFragmentImpl.transformChildren(IrModuleFragmentImpl.kt:45)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoidKt.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:330)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.lower(ComposableFunctionBodyTransformer.kt:453)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeIrGenerationExtension.generate(ComposeIrGenerationExtension.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory$generateModule$1.invoke(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory$generateModule$1.invoke(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:89)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.Psi2IrTranslator.generateModuleFragment(Psi2IrTranslator.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:106)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:595)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:211)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:154)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:169)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:386)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:110)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:286)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:114)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:607)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1659)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)



Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details
```

Comment: Tried without issues with beta03, kotlin compiler 1.4.31

Comment: Cool! Will upgrade and check

Comment: If the problem still occurs, create a sample project that demonstrates the problem and file a bug report. This would be appear to be a problem with the Compose Kotlin compiler plugin.

Comment: Still the same issue after upgrading to beta-03, Kotlin compiler - 1.4.31. Where do I report this?

Comment: You can create an issue on IssueTracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128&template=1253476

Comment: Please not that this error is thrown only when `Text() ` is included within a layout like `Column`.